# Why do I get "mysql: unknown option '-▒'" error on execution of mysql command performing any query?

Tags: mysql, mariadb-10.5

On the execution of the following command in linux

```
mysql --host=HOST --user=USER -–password='password' DATABASE --execute='SHOW TABLES'
```

I get the following error

```
mysql: unknown option '-▒'
```

This output does not depend on execute command and it is same for any password whether it is correct or wrong.
This is on shared hosting. Please advise what can I do about it?

Comment: Have you copy-pasted the command line? It seems like there's some invisible character in there. Try to simply type the command.

Comment: Look closely at the `--password`, not all hyphens were created equal.

Comment: I typed the command playing with different parameters, their different order and also short equivalents like "-p" and provided password with and without quotes. It looks like this happens only when password is provided, when it is not then I am prompted for password and everything looks ok. But I need to have it non interactive.